# Script which allows to know Joomla 3 configuration.php details

Tags: php, configuration, joomla

I've one Joomla 3 project. I'm doing this project unformally. So I'm afraid that my money wouldn't be vanished. 
Does anyone know where is the best place (in Joomla 3 files) to hide script which would allow to view information of a configuration.php and how that script should be like?

I'm asking this question because I've tried insert a tiny script in include/framework.php bet I get an error.

Thank you,

Ugnius

Comment: Sounds like a nice security hole waiting to happen.

Comment: It would be temporary.

Comment: well if you are able to put a script onto the server arent you able to download a script as well, just download the configuration.php file and open it.

Comment: But I want to know configuration details in case ftp username and password would be changed.

Comment: then get the ftp login from the owner?

Comment: I've ftp login know but I'm afraid that the owner of the web will change it. With that script I will secure myself if the money of my work isn't be paid.

Comment: then develop the site on your server first, let them see it, get paid then upload the site to their server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla has is own method of getting variables from the configuration.php file however do use with caution:

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
echo 'Site name is ' . $config->getValue( 'config.sitename' );
echo 'Site name is ' . $config->getValue( 'config.offline_message' );
echo 'Site name is ' . $config->getValue( 'config.dbtype' );
```

and so on.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, sorry, I can't vote up your answer because I haven't enough reputation.

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas - You can accept it to mark it as solved by clicking the "tick" icon underneath ;)